# pass an array of array in a subroutine

Tags: arrays, fortran

If I have the following code ([thanks to M. Chinoune](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44388808/syntax-to-access-in-a-ragged-array)) in a subroutine

```
type :: vector
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: elements
end type vector

type :: ragged_array
    type(vector), dimension(:), allocatable :: vectors
end type ragged_array

type(ragged_array) :: raggar

allocate( raggar%vectors(2) )
allocate( raggar%vectors(1)%elements(3) )
allocate( raggar%vectors(2)%elements(4) )

raggar%vectors(1)%elements=0 
raggar%vectors(2)%elements=0
```

if I want to pass `raggar` in an other subroutine to modify size of `raggar`. should I do something like :

```
CALL MySubroutine(raggar)
```

or

```
CALL MySubroutine(raggar%vectors%elements)
```

And then, in my subroutine how can I declare it ?

```
SUBROUTINE MySubroutine(raggar)
type :: vector
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: elements
end type vector

type :: ragged_array
    type(vector), dimension(:), allocatable :: vectors
end type ragged_array

type(ragged_array), INTENT(INOUT):: raggar
```

I did many tried but I always get error such as :

`The type of the actual argument differs from the types of the dummy argument.`

or

`the shape matching rules of actual arguments and dummy argument have been violated`

Comment: Place your type definition into a module and use this module in your program and subroutine.

Comment: also you have a mess with ragarr, raggarr and raggar

Comment: Oh sorry, it was error because of typing (I have one computer with internet and the other with code....) I have corrected...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place type definitions into a module and use it in a program and subroutine.

```
module my
type :: vector
    integer, dimension(:), allocatable :: elements
end type vector

type :: ragged_array
    type(vector), dimension(:), allocatable :: vectors
end type ragged_array
end module

program probe
use my
type(ragged_array) :: ragarr
allocate( ragarr%vectors(2) )
allocate( ragarr%vectors(1)%elements(3) )
allocate( ragarr%vectors(2)%elements(4) )
ragarr%vectors(1)%elements=0 
ragarr%vectors(2)%elements=0 
CALL MySubroutine(ragarr)
end program

SUBROUTINE MySubroutine(rr)
use my
type(ragged_array), INTENT(INOUT):: rr
end subroutine
```

Comment: I already have a module with my subroutines, is it better to create two separated module ? o can I but the subroutine in the same module ? thx! (because I want to call the subroutine in an other subroutine)

Comment: This module contains the types shared by the main program and the subroutine. If you already have a module used by program and subroutine, you can place the definitions there.

Comment: Ok it work ! thanks a lot, and if I want to duplicate `rr` in  `MySubroutine` is there an equivalent of `size(rr)` ?

Comment: I have found a way using a loop reading each size of each `elements` ! thanks you so much to make me understand modules ! !