# Realize an array which the second dimension depends on the first argument

Tags: arrays, fortran

Suppose I have an array `A[a,b]`. The dimension of `a` is `2`. When `a=1`, the dimension of `b` is `3`; when `a=2`, the dimension of `b` is 6.

For example, one array `A` looks like

```
[[1,2,3]
[4,5,6,7,8,9]]
```

it is combined from `1*3` and `1*6`. In total 9 entries, not from input.

Is there any method to define such an array in Fortran? or I need other type of data structure?

Comment: Also see the comments at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49304186/append-to-3d-array-to-enable-first-dimensions-differing-in-length-among-the-3rd?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to provide a better description of what you want to do.  With `allocatable` entities you can trivially achieve what you have described.

```
program foo
  integer a, b
  real, allocatable :: x(:,:)
  read(*,*) a
  if (a == 1 .or. a == 2) then
     b = 3 * a
     allocate(x(a,b))
   else
     stop 'Is this right?'
  end if
  x = 1
  print *, shape(x)
end program foo
```

Comment: edited. sorry for the confusing.